# too many symbolic links after executing php artisan migrate?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

i tried to run php artisan migrate , but it shows this error

[image: error]

env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=APP
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

running xampp vm , laravel 5.5

Comment: Can you able to post your migration?

Comment: The image isn't a screenshot of an error.

Comment: Also, you should upload the image directly to here.

Comment: Please post your full error message that you're getting, here as text instead of an image.

Comment: I posted it , now I edited the post

Comment: I think you need to double check, as it's you're DB details in that image.

Comment: i am running phpmyadmin , the database totally created fine .

Comment: This is an error from the actual mysql service, not from your laravel code. From googling, it seems to happen more often with MariaDB.

Comment: Are you actually running the database server on 33060, or should it be the default 3306?

Comment: yes , however i figured out phpmyadmin is using mariadb not mysql

Comment: @aynber it's the default ,

Comment: You will need to change the port in your code to 3306, then. Right now you have it set to 33060.

Comment: i changed it , still same error @aynber